# I am getting error message in Selenium Webdriver code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Error message

Aug 01, 2014 5:07:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@169751d

Code:

```
public void login(){
    WebElement loginBtn;
    loginBtn= driver.findElement(By.className("cr-btn"));
    //loginBtn.click();
```

Comment: How is your driver instantiated?  Please provide a self-contained, or at least more thorough, example.

Comment: You might want to consider giving your question a title which doesn't apply to nearly every problem ever asked on this site!

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Firefox plugin issue. I googled for 3 hours and found the solution for it!

To solve it you have to close the driver in your @After part like that:

```
    @After             
    public void Ending() {    
            try{    
              driver.close();
              Thread.sleep(3000);
               }
           catch(Exception b){
              b.getMessage();
               }
     }
```

Good luck!

Comment: I had the above problem and your solution fixed it. Thanks.